# Using image404 with azurereader2 in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, azure, imageresizer

I am using following plugin to resizes images in ASP.net application AzureReader2 works fine image404 works fine seprately but when I try to access blob url it does not redirect and it is giving

```
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

http://imageresizing.net/plugins/image404

http://imageresizing.net/plugins/azurereader2

Any one used image404 with azurereader2? is it compatible with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14675118/175679

Comment: This isn't a duplicate question. The linked question asks about what URL to use to get AzureReader2 to work. This question is asking specifically about the compatibility of two plugins from the same vendor. I'm having the same issue getting Image404 to work with AzureReader2.

Comment: I would like to see an answer to this as well!

Comment: Please tag this [imageresizer] so the folks there can find it.

Comment: Was there ever a solution for this?

Comment: @Ryan what is exactly the issue? this seems to work fine for me

Comment: @ahmelsayed I'm using the AzureReader2 with this configuration: `<add name="AzureReader2" prefix="~/blob/" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" endpoint="http://127.0.0.1:10000/" />` and the image404 plugin `<image404 default="blob/img/profile404.jpg?cache=always" />` and I just get a 404 error. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 with the MVC shim as well.

Comment: Can you use fiddler (or similar tool) to check where you are getting the 404 from.

Comment: If I go to `http://localhost:22841/blob/img/site/2/profile.jpg?width=270&height=270&404=default` I get "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found." in the browser.. I get the stack trace of the AzureReader2 code `e:\projects\azure-sdk-for-net\microsoft-azure-api\Services\Storage\Lib\DotNetCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:620`

Comment: Here's the stack trace: http://notepad.cc/kucofu97

Answer (score 1):

This bug has now been fixed, as of release 3.4.3.

See http://imageresizing.net/releases/3-4-3