# Imageresizer across multiple containers in azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, image-resizing

Im uploading images to azure blob storage in a project. For logic reason I'm creating a new container for each upload, to group the content. This park works fine. Now I'm trying to setup [ImageResizer](https://imageresizing.net/) to enable resizing :) and som other stuff. In all the examples they point to a container as the endpoint, but in my case I have multiple dynamic container, so this is not an option. My question is if someone knows if it should work in my case or if I need to rethink something about the way I store images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your requirement, you could try to leverage [AzureReader2](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/azurereader2) to work with Azure blobs, in order to dynamic resize your images from Azure Blob. Since you have miltiple dynamic containers, you could follow the steps below to configure `AzureReader2`:

**Install Package via NuGet**

- ImageResizer.WebConfig
- ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2

**Web.config**

```
<configSections>
    <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<resizer>
    <plugins>
      <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
      <add name="AzureReader2"
           connectionString="{your-storage-connectionstring}"
           prefix="~/cloud/" />
    </plugins>
</resizer>

<system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

**Result**

Here is my test, you could refer to it.

1.Upload images to my Azure Blob

https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/images01/test.jpg

https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/images01/landscape/test.jpg

https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/images02/test.jpg

2.Browser images in my web site as follows:

http://bruce-chen.azurewebsites.net/cloud/images01/test.jpg?width=400

http://bruce-chen.azurewebsites.net/cloud/images01/landscape/test.jpg?width=400

http://bruce-chen.azurewebsites.net/cloud/images02/test.jpg?width=400

**Note:** your images links should look like:

`http(s)://<host-name>:<port>/<prefix-you-configured>/<blob-container-name>/<blob-file-name>?width=200&height=200`

Additionally, for pre-resizing your images via ImageResizer, you could follow the answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690577/if-using-imageresizer-with-azure-blobs-do-i-need-the-azurereader2-plugin). Also, there is anther similar library called [Simple.ImageResizer](https://github.com/terjetyl/Simple.ImageResizer) which is free, you could refer to it.

Comment: Thanks, must have an error in my web.config as this looks my setup. Do you have the httpmodules included?

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing it out. It actually was similar to my current config. It turned out the error was the first part of the url. I used the blobs direct url and not the sites url ;) as mentioned in of of the comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675118/imageresizer-for-azure-using-azurereader2-plugin-not-resizing

Why are you using the shim, haven't seen it before?